# Visual Studio 12 compiler detecting non existent parameters in action and failing to build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am attempting to build a solution and am getting the following compiler error:

```
6>C:\...\File.cs(83,106,83,112): error CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action<string,Adapters.Adapter.AdapterInfo>' does not take 1 arguments
```

Ok, so the compiler thinks I am trying to call a delegate with only one argument when it requires two. But lets take a look at the line it's complaining about:

```
SomeString.OnChange<AdapterInfo>(adapterInfo => { ... });
```

The signature of OnChange is this:

```
public static IDisposable OnChange<T>(this string path, Action<T> action, params Func<T, bool>[] where)
```

All the code seems to indicate that the Action generated by that lambda has one argument of type AdapterInfo, yet somehow the compiler thinks there is a string involved in there. Any ideas how this could happen and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to result from my using an object that contains an FSharpSet, without having the FSharp.Core.dll as a reference. Seems strange but when I added the dll the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles just fine for me.

Have you tried BUILD -> Clean Solution?